# Facebook recommend this site to a friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to achieve this but i dont know what i should use. I looked [here first](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations)

If a new user registers to the site and non of their friends have registered when they click on a add friend button

1. Find friends via Facebook
2. Post To F/B Wall (Message "Hey all i am really enjoying this site, come visit.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin is basically an optional shout, if you want more versatility you should make your own calls on the Graph API yourself, allowing you to find out more details about the user and their friends.